# HibernateCursorItemReader with Hibernate Detached criteria

Tags: hibernate, spring-batch, detachedcriteria

How to use hibernate detached criteria with "HibernateCursorItemReader" of spring batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution could be the following:

1. create a custom `HibernateDetachedCriteriaItemReader<> extends AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader<>`
2. add a property `Criteria criteria` and inject it before use
3. rewrite all `do*()` functions to manage resultset lifecycle

Or extends from `HibernateCursorItemReader` and override doOpen() to let working in dual-mode (normal,with detached criteria)